# How to 'set path' automatically when opening Vim from a directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, vim, macvim

I'm trying to get `:A` (e.g. switch between controller and spec) working in vim-rails. If I navigate to my rails project, run `vim .`, open a controller file and run `:A`, I get the error:

```
E345: Can't find file "app/controllers/widgets_controller.rb" in path
```

If I then set the path explicitly:

```
:set path=/Users/me/Documents/Code/my-project
```

then `:A` works as expected. How can I set the path initially when I open a directory with Vim?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly when opening a directory: since you seem to be working with projects, give the [project plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=69) a try.

Using that, you could execute arbitrary commands when entering or leaving a project.

From the plugin description:

> You can use this plugin's basic functionality to set up a list of 
>   frequently-accessed files for easy navigation. The list of files 
>   will be displayed in a window on the left side of the Vim 
>   window, and you can press  or double-click on 
>   filenames in the list to open the files. This is similar to how 
>   some IDEs I've used work. I find this easier to use than 
>   having to navigate a directory hierarchy with the file-explorer. 
>   It also obviates the need for a buffer explorer because you 
>   have your list of files on the left of the Vim Window.

Comment: interesting, thanks eckes - looks promising. will try this out tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do to have a local .vimrc file per project:

- In my ~/.vimrc file I define the following:

```
let s:project_root = finddir('.git/..', expand('%:p:h').';')
let s:local_vimrc = join([s:project_root, '.vimrc'], '/')

if filereadable(s:local_vimrc)
    exec "source " . s:local_vimrc
endif
```

- In the project root (which usually has a .git dir) I do the following:

```sh
touch /path/to/project/.vimrc
```

- In the .vimrc file, I prepend the path variable (notice the ^path).  Using :set path^= instead of :set path+= prepends the new directory to the beginning of the path instead of appending it to the end.  This makes it faster for the find command to search for your files.

```
let s:project_root = finddir('.git/..', expand('%:p:h').';')
exec 'setlocal path^='.s:project_root

setlocal wildmode=longest,list,full
setlocal wildmenu
setlocal tags=/path/to/project/root/tags
```

Now the :find command should only display files and directories relative to the project root.